# Pyspark: Incorrect date when save into Cassandra

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I am new to Spark and Cassandra. I prepared a data frame and saved it into Cassandra. The dates between Pyspark and Cassandra are not consistent.

Pyspark shows '2020-10-04'.
Cassandra shows '2020-10-03 16:00:00.000000+0000'.

Any idea how to resolve it?

In Pyspark,

```
>>> df_check.show()
+-----------+-----+
|access_date|count|
+-----------+-----+
| 2020-10-04|  120|
+-----------+-----+

>>> df_check.printSchema()
root
 |-- access_date: date (nullable = true)
 |-- count: long (nullable = false)
```

In Cassandra,

```
cqlsh:test> select * from test2;

 access_date                     | count
---------------------------------+-------
 2020-10-03 16:00:00.000000+0000 |   120


cqlsh:test> desc test2;

CREATE TABLE test.test2 (
    access_date timestamp PRIMARY KEY,
    count int
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cassandra stores the timestamp in UTC, and in your case you're converting the date that Spark is showing date/timestamp in your local timezone (UTC+8) to the UTC.  You can try to workaround that by setting `spark.sql.session.timeZone` to UTC, so Spark will work with dates in that time zone, but that may change your data, especially if you're using functions like `current_date`/`current_timestamp`.

P.S. You can read more about handling of date/timestamp in the Spark in the [following blog post](https://databricks.com/blog/2020/07/22/a-comprehensive-look-at-dates-and-timestamps-in-apache-spark-3-0.html).